# Prove that $G$ has at most $2$ normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Problem**
> Let $G$ be a non-abelian group satisfying the following condition.
>   "$N_1\nsubseteq N_2$ for all non-trivial normal subgroups $N_1\neq N_2\subset G$"
>   Show that $G$ has at most $2$ normal subgroups.

I found that if $G$ has two non-trivial normal subgroups $N_1\neq N_2, G=N_1\times N_2$ because $N_1\cap N_2=1, N_1N_2=G$ from the condition. But  I don't know the next step.

Comment: If you are to show that $G$ has at most two non-trivial, proper normal subgroups, then assuming it has two won't usually get you anywhere. Assuming it has _three_, on the other hand, ought to lead somewhere.

Comment: @Arthur I tried assuming $G$ has three. But I can't find what to do next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume $N_1$ is non-abelian, since $G$ is non-abelian.

Assume $N_3$ is the third non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$, then as you did, $G = N_1\times N_3$ and $G = N_2\times N_3$. In particular, $N_3$ is commutative with both $N_1$ and $N_2$.

Now suppose $(g_1,g_2)\in N_3\le G$ with $g_1\in N_1$ and $g_2\in N_2$. Since $N_3$ is commutative with $N_1$, we have $g_1\in Z(N_1)$. But $Z(N_1)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N_1$, and thus a normal subgroup of $G$, it must be trivial or the whole $N_1$. By assumption, $N_1$ is non-abelian and so $Z(N_1) =1$. Hence, $g_1 = 1$. This gives $N_3 = 1$ or $N_3 = N_2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why may we assume that $N_1$ is non-abelian? There are non-abelian groups with abelian normal subgroups.

Comment: It's a usual exercise to show that if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two normal subgroups with trivial intersection, then they commute i.e. for all $(x,y)\in N_1\times N_2$, $xy=yx$. Thus if $N_1$ and $N_2$ were abelian, so would $G=N_1 N_2$.

Comment: $G$ is non-abelian, and so one of $N_1$ and $N_2$ must be non-abelian.@Javi